# saving hasMany always add record instead of updating

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.2

I have a `hasMany` relationship (let's say `Post` hasMany `Comments`)

I want to edit both the `Post` and an existing `Comment` at the same time

**My code**

in my comment `edit.ctp` file I did

```
<?= $this->Form->create($post); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('title'); ?> 
<?= $this->Form->input('title');  ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('text'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('comments.0.id'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('comments.0.text'); ?>
```

and in my `PostsController`

```
$post= $this->Posts->get($id);
$post= $this->Posts->patchEntity($post, $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['Comments']]);
```

**My problem**

now I expect that the comment will be updated, instead cake adds a new comment every time.

**What did I do**

I tried to debug `$this->request->data` and I got

```
[
    'text' => 'This is a test',
    'comments' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'id' => '168',
            'text' => 'Comment test',

        ]
    ]
]
```

but if I debug `$post` I get

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Post) {

    /* ... */
    'comments' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Comment) {

            'text' => 'Comment test',
            '[new]' => true,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [
                'text' => true
            ],
            /* ... */

        }
    ],
    /* ... */
    '[dirty]' => [
        'comments' => true,
    ],

}
```

So why comment is marked as 'new' when I pass its `id` to the controller?

Of course this is an over simplified version of my actual situation. Maybe the problem it's not in the above code and i have to look elsewhere in my other code.

My question here is if I'm doing some basic approach error.

Comment: you can delete old records for saving new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the associated data into your entity in order to be able to patch it, otherwise the data won't be merged, but just marshalled, and thus ends up being handled as "new".

Automatically loading associated data only happens for the special `_ids` key, and when there is at least one entry in the association property, ie actually you don't need to have the associated data loaded that you want to patch, but there must be *something* in order for the marshaller to reach the point where data is being read and merged.

To be exact, without any data in the `comments` property, the marshaller will step out here

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.2.8/src/ORM/Marshaller.php#L653-L655**

I can't really tell whether there might be a bug, at the very least I guess the docs would need to be updated around this, as they would be a little misleading. While they do try to explain what happens when associated data is missing in the source entity, the shown example currently doesn't work, and they say that new entities would only be created for `belongsTo` and `hasOne` associations, which is incorrect.

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Patching HasMany and BelongsToMany](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#patching-hasmany-and-belongstomany)**

You may want to file an issue over at GitHub for clarification.

## tl;dr

Long story short, contain the comments and you should be good.

```
$post = $this->Posts->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Comments']
]);
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great. Not only that part of the manual is confusing, but also [this one](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data) imho.

Comment: @arilia It would surely help if that example would include the code that reads the data, given that you actually _must_ read the data, and this isn't a bug.

Comment: @arilia I've opened an issue over at `cakephp/docs`. **https://github.com/cakephp/docs/issues/3952**

Comment: Thanks ndm. I would have opened a ticket by myself but I'm not so good at writing in english and I would not have been so clear